# Custom URLs in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I'm trying to write a simple CMS in rails that will allow text urls rather than the standard `/posts/show/<id>`.
I have a model that has a title and body, I would like to replace spaces in the title and use it as the url.
I also want to have the url at the root level, not past /pages/show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do what I wanted to do.
I am setting a route to the root url with a parameter like this `(config/routes.rb)`:

```
  get ':title', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
```

Now I have a pages controller that was generated by `rails generate scaffold Page title:string body:text`
which has a function set_page which I changed to do this `(app/controllers/pages_controller.rb)`:

```
def set_page  
  @page = Page.find_by("title" => params[:title])  
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this gem [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), is used for create url from fields of the model storing it on database. Otherwise, you can create the route that you want example get 'pages/show', home#index and pointing wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

While the friendly_id gem is really nice, it's quite heavy for such a simple need. You might consider a lighter alternative approach : https://github.com/johnotander/urls_for_humans

Answer (score 1):

You can override your rails urls by setting them like this:

```
get 'posts' => 'posts#index'
```

In your routes.

But since you want to format the url for the show action (which depends on a specific id for each item in posts) your best bet is to use the awesome **friendly_id** gem.

See: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Some resources:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails